# how to pass hash map as a parameter to JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a hashMap parameter which contains `<Sting,Value>` now i would like to pass these values into two JPA columns.

```
SELECT obj from x obj where x.no=?<String goes here> and x.amount=?<value goes here >
```

how can i  do this using JPQL ?

Comment: key will be known to you beforehand or you want to iterate through the map to execute the query for all the key-value pairs?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia i want to iterate through the map to execute the query for all the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this loop you can iterate through the `Map` to execute `select statements` for all the key-value pairs:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT obj from x obj where x.no=:x_no and x.amount=:x_amt");
List<ResultObj> resultList = new ArrayList<ResultObj>();
Iterator<Entry<String, Value>> iter = yourMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, Value> next = iter.next();
    Value value = next.getValue();
    query.setParameter("x_no", next).setParameter("x_amt", value);
    ResultObj result = (ResultObj) query.getSingleResult();
    resultList.add(result);
}
```

Comment: Having this line '(ResultObj) query.getSingleResult();' in loop may connect more to DB right?

Comment: i didn't understand! for every `x_no` and `x_amount` you will have different `ResultObj`. is this what you want.. right?

Comment: I need it as List<ResultObj> from the given parameters and i expect the connection to be made in DB at once(My hashmap never be more than 1000 values)

Comment: One `EntityManager` instance represents a connection to the database and  in a multithreaded application every thread usually has its own `EntityManager` instance. As you are not creating entityManagers in each iteration, a single DB connection will be used to execute all the select statements. And I have updated my answer to store the ResultObjs in one `List<ResultObj>`.

Comment: on update, object state will be synchronized with Db state during transaction commit.

Answer (score 2):

According [to this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/jpql), you can use the KEY() and VALUE(), and in your case, it would give something like this:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT obj from x obj where x.no=KEY(:mapParam) and x.amount=VALUE(:mapParam)");
query.setParamters("mapParam", yourMap);
query.getResultList();
```

Be careful though, you need to be on JPA 2.0, and there was some problems with Hibernate, that was fixed since the time, but still, you have to be on a fixed version (4.1.4+). See [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5396).